# Trying to Run Kivy Application on MacOS, but getting black screen when run

Tags: python, macos, kivy, kivy-language

I have been trying to run my kivy application on my Mac, however when I run it all I get is a black screen. I have tried doing everything that I can, however I simply cannot get it to work. I have also tried manually loading the kv file, but that also did not work.

Here is my Python Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random


kivy.require('2.0.0') 

class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def generate_number(self):
        self.random_label.text = str(random.randint(0, 1000))

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()

Test = Test()
Test.run()
```

Here is my KV File:

```
<MyRoot>:

    random_label: random_label
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Random'
            font_size: 64
            color: 0.92, 0.45, 0
        Label:
            id: random_label
            text: '-'
            font_size: 64

        Button:
            text: 'Generate'
            font_size: 32
            size: 100, 50
            on_press: root.generate_number()
```

Comment: Found no issue. The program should run as expected when .kv file is in the same directory as .py with name `test.kv`. You can check the log file for any warning, error etc. Make sure kivy is installed properly with all the necessary dependencies. If nothing works, try reinstalling it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but where would the log files be located?

Comment: In the same directory as your `main.py` with name possibly `.kivy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue was with the python version I ran it with Python 3.10 instead of 3.9 and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a wild guess that your kivy file is not correctly named. According to the [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html),

> By name convention:
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> `MyApp -> my.kv`

I put the kivy script in the same directory as the python script, and named the kivy script `test.kv`. The file structure looks like this:

```
.
├── main.py
└── test.kv
```

It produces a window with some texts and buttons.

Tell me if it solves your problem.

Comment: No, I actually used the correct filenames and placed both of the files in the same directory, but it still isn’t working. Did you test it on MacOS or Windows?

Comment: @Nag That's odd. I am using macOS, Python3.10, and Kivy2.1.0 all the newest versions.